# Film with two children who can temporarily communicate telepathically in a castle

Tags: story-identification, telepathy

I watched this film on TV, possibly around 2006-08. I can't recall if it used any CGI, but it seemed quite modern, as if it had been made in the 90s - early 2000s.

I think it was a fantasy film, but I can't remember the plot. All I'm sure of is there were two children, both with brown hair, possibly around 10/11, and I think the girl was older than the boy.

The only scene I can remember is one in which they're in some kind of underground dungeon or chamber, and realise that they can speak telepathically to each other- I think it's limited to/caused by the room, rather than being a super power they have.

I think I can remember some of the lines?

> Girl "Hey, think something to me"

Then I think the boy said something and they laughed.

Comment: Maybe the witch mountain remake? Not ringing any other bells.

Comment: @JohnP hmm, not sure; I've seen the "return to witch mountain"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *[Spy Kids 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_Kids_2:_The_Island_of_Lost_Dreams)* both the characters are stuck in dungeon and can speak telepathically because of the place, after which the skeletons chase them. The movie was released in 2002.

[This review](http://decentfilms.com/reviews/spykids2) mentions the telepathy angle:

> Even more weirdly, Carmen and Juni find that while in the temple they’re incapable of speech, but can hear one another’s thoughts. This also goes nowhere and does nothing, and eventually goes away. Toward the end of the film, long after they’ve resumed talking, there’s a sudden brief relapse into telepathy that’s given no attention at all. None of this is either explained or made use of in the story.

Comment: Interestingly enough, a friend started showing me this movie recently. If I'd stayed just a little longer... :D thanks for finding it :)